# Draw two bar graph on top each other

Tags: matlab, plot

I have two information and want them to be displayed at the same time.

```
 f=     1.4000    0.8000


 d=    8.0000    8.2000
```

I used several codes here is one example:

```
 bar([d, f], 'stacked'); 
 legend(' ', ' '); 
 xlabel('every 5 Run of runs'); 
 ylabel(' ')
 axis([0 T  0 N])
 hold on;
```

What I am getting :

1:the two legends and graph are of the same color

2:they are displayed one after the other.

3:the two info are read at same run 1 and 2 what I have here 4 runs

[image: Result]

how to solve? I want both to be displayed at run 1 and 2 on top of each other with different colors of course.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `d` and `f` are defined as

```
f= [1.4000,0.8000];
d= [8.0000,8.2000];
```

and you do this

```
bar([d', f'], 1.5);   %Where 1.5 is the width of the bars.
```

You will get them on top of each other.
The difference being that `[d, f]` is now a `2x2` matrix instead of a `1x4` row vector.

Comment: thanks @Webfoot Witch Hat
although they are not 100% on top both maybe this is better. you saved my life

Comment: @pac I guess the amount of overlapping is adjustable but if you really want them stacked on top of each other just change the `width` to `'stacked'`.